# How do I make xticks equidistant, despite their value?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph contaminants measured in a sample over time, and some sample dates are closer together. How do I plot this line with the current datetime values, but make each xtick equidistant?

This is what I've got so far, currently the ticks are bunched together when the samples were taken closer together.

```
date = df_TCE.SAMPLEDATE.unique()

date_IA14 = df_TCE.SAMPLEDATE[df_TCE.SYS_LOC_CODE == 'IA-14']

IA14 = df_TCE.AL_RESULT_VALUE[df_TCE.SYS_LOC_CODE == 'IA-14']

plt.plot(date_IA14, IA14)

plt.title('TCE Time Series')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Contaminant Level')
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xticks(date_IA14)
ax.set_yticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
ax.set_facecolor('seashell')

plt.show()
```

This is the output with the ticks bunched:

[`Output`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRmbZ.png)

Comment: In general you do not want to have equal spacing between unequal ticks/data. This can very easily lead to wrong conclusions. Instead one would usually plot the data as it is, but tick the graph with equally spaced tickmarks, which then do not necessarily correspond to the data points shown, but allow to draw the right conclusions (like "change per month", "spikes on mondays" etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can try.

First, ensure that your dataframe series called `SAMPLEDATE` are datetime objects by running `pandas.to_datetime(df_TCE.SAMPLEDATE)`. Resolve any parsing errors that arise so that you're truly dealing with a datetime x-axis rather than strings.

Then, check out `fig.autofmt_xdate()` instead of `ax.set_xticks(date_IA14)`. Once our x axis is filled with proper datetime objects, `matplotlib` is smart enough to get us to reasonable xtick spacing.

If you dislike the defaults, check out `matplotlib.dates.DayLocator()` or the HourLocator() or the MonthLocator(), whatever meets your regular interval needs. You can apply it to your axes object like this:
`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.DayLocator())`

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DayLocator